# jquery autocomplete select event

Tags: jquery

I am using the autocomplete to display items that contain html markup such as <sup>T128</sup>
The first script will display the autocomplete list, but not as html..it will display <sup>T128</sup> in the list, but I can select the item:

```
    var createAutocomplete = function () {
    var $input = $(this);
    var options = {
        source: $input.attr("data-jax-autocomplete"),
        minLength: 3
    };
    $input.autocomplete(options)
    };
```

I found a fix that will render the html markup in the autocomplete list, but after changing the script, I found that I can no longer select an item on the list:

```
    var createAutocomplete = function () {
    var $input = $(this);
    var options = {
        source: $input.attr("data-jax-autocomplete"),
        minLength: 3
    };


    $input.autocomplete(options).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li")
          .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
          .appendTo(ul);
    };

};
```

Comment: what happens when you try to select it?

Comment: Nothing...that is the question that I am asking. In the first example I could select an item from the autocomplete list and it would be displayed in the input. In the second example when I click on an item in the autocomplete list nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using the [jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js extension by Scott](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/autocomplete/html.html)